# Not able to install kubectl on Google Compute Engine (GCE)?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I'm trying to spin up a Kubernetes (k8s) cluster on GCE. When I run

```
gcloud components update kubectl
```

on a Windows machine I get

> ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The following components are unknown [kubectl]

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update (May 2016): As of [late March 2016](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#march_29_2016), gcloud will now install kubectl for windows.

---

gcloud won't currently install kubectl on windows (hence the error). You can download a recent kubectl binary directly from GCS instead (`gsutil cp gs://kubernetes-release/release/v1.0.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe kubectl.exe`).

Since kubectl is much less heavily tested on windows than on Mac/Linux, you may need to pass the `--kubeconfig` argument if it isn't finding your configuration file in the default location (`gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME` should write to `.kube/config` in your home directory and kubectl should read from the same file).

Comment: Seems to be `gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME` these days.

Comment: As mentioned the configuration file is generated to your %HOME% folder. If you don't have a %HOME% folder specified it will just silently fail. It looks like the file is generated but isn't. Use the UI or SET to assign a %HOME% environment variable and you should see the .kube folder get generated there after running the command.

Comment: It seems that the windows kubectl.exe binary is keeping pace with the rest of the project. For example, one can find the versions available with `gsutil.cmd ls gs://kubernetes-release/release` and then download say 1.2.4 as follows `gsutil.cmd cp gs://kubernetes-release/release/v1.2.4/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe kubectl.exe`

Comment: @BradT: gcloud now supports kubectl on windows (and will help automatically keep you up to date). I've updated the answer.

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this - gcloud installs a 16 bit version of kubectl which doesn't run on 64 bit windows - you still need to download manually using the above steps

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a little (don't they always).

This just worked for me..

```
gcloud components install kubectl
```